# Не могу собрать проект на андроиде с гитхаба

Tags: java, android, github, apk

Есть проект на гитхабе, на java, под android. Вот этот:
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_mms

Я его склонировал, скачал. Но я не могу понять, как его собрать в apk. Даже не могу понять, какую документацию почитать, чтобы разобраться со сборкой этого проекта.
Андроид-студия есть, Netbeans есть, Eclipse скачал, сижу, изучаю документацию по нему. Знания технического английского тоже есть. Умение и любовь читать документацию тоже есть.
Вопрос в том, в каком направлении читать? Подскажите документацию, где разобраться, как такой проект собирать в apk?
Попробовал открыть его в Eclipse, он там открылся, но build серого цвета, недоступен. А при попытке сделать run, ругается, что нечего запускать и всё.
В Netbeans открывается, но не собирается. В андроид-студии сделал импорт, но вылезло куча зависимостей, которые не хотят ресолвиться.
Как это проект собрать?? Или, хотя бы, у кого спросить, как его собрать?
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Это старый проект, написанный судя по всему на Eclipse. Когда открываете студию, нажмите `Esc`, чтобы не грузился проект, и в появившемся окне выберите `Import Project` и укажите путь к скаченной с Гитхаб директории с проектом.

Comment: Не работает совет. Прогресс в том, что оно таки сделало импорт и даже прикрутило к нему Gradle. Но там куча зависимостей, которые не ресолвятся. Например: import android.database.sqlite.SqliteWrapper;
import android.os.SystemProperties;
и ещё куча.

Comment: Ну так это системное приложение и в коде использует не публичное API, которое в студии для простых смертных скрыто. Тут как минимум нужен специальный android.jar вместо тех, что лежат в SDK/platforms... В общем надо рыть в сторону сборки/модификации системных приложений. Плюс к этому для установки его на девайс потребуется специальная подпись и/или рут/мод прошивки.

Comment: Это же opensource проект, под стандартной лицензией апача. Который может скачать и собрать любой желающий. Как это может быть с непубличным API? Или я что-то неправильно понимаю? И где тогда брать все эти непубличные вещи? Оно же open source. Как тогда его мониторили и допиливали?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот что ответил мне один из разработчиков, кто коммитил в этот код:
I don't know if that code can be compiled as a separate app. It is usually compiled as part of the entire AOSP project, using `make`.

То есть - этот проект, это часть Android Open Source Project. И компилиться он может только как часть AOSP, с помощью 'make'.